# WEKA simple CLI command Killed

Tags: command, data-mining, weka, arff, web-mining

I Run following code on WEKA SimpleCLI tool

> java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir c:/mydir/ > c:/output/result.arff

and it showed following result

[...Killed]
Finished redirecting output to 'c:/output/result.arff'

the result.arff file size is 0 KB.

Anyone know the problems?

/* My data about 63 thousand file of *.txt
   but when i try with 10 sample of those data it does work */

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you run out of memory?

Isn't there some error message reported? Is that the complete output you shared?

Comment: yes that's the complete output. I don't think that i've run out of memory..cause i already try it at another computer with higher spec..the problem still occured..

Comment: Make sure you let Java use all your memory. **By default, Java will not use all your memory.** It assumes that you usually want to be able to run other tasks in parallel. Depending on your setting, you may be running Weka with just 256m RAM (this is, in fact, the default setting for Weka on many systems.) Java defaults usually are to use 25% of your memory.